# Replacing all occurrences of words from a given set, but only if the word is not contained within another word

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of stopwords that I wish to remove from content that I parse through. The list is pretty exhaustive and contains a lot of pronouns and other common words, such as `was`, `being`, `our`, etc. but unfortunately also `i`, `a`, `just` and others.

I wish to remove all occurrences of these stopwords, but **only** if they are surrounded by whitespace (including tab and newline).

I'm thinking that a regular expression would be needed here, but is it possible to have a regular expression with a variable inside of it?

As I'm doing this in Python, I would have something like:

```
for word in stopwords:
    text = text.replace(`regex for current word`, '')
```

Is this doable? What would the regex be in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up realizing that regex is way overkill for what I wanted to do, as I would usually only have a single whitespace around the words I wanted to remove

In the end, I just went for this:

```
for word in commonWords :
    text = text.replace(' '+word+' ', ' ')
```

Comment: This will not work if the `word` is at start or end.

Comment: True, but `word` is usually such that it is not located at the start or end of the document, such as `Disclaimer`, `Copyright`, `owner`, etc. In other words, I found it an acceptable trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the word between two `\b`:

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = "this is a test and retest"
>>> re.sub(r'\btest\b', '****', txt)
'this is a **** and retest'
```

as in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) for `\b`:

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.... This means that `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo'`, `'foo.'`, `'(foo)'`,`'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar'` or `'foo3'`.

Comment: This will also replace `.word.`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|\s)your_word(?:\s|$)
```

This should do it for you.Use it with `re.sub`.

```
re.sub(r"(?:^|\s)word(?:\s|$)","",word)
```

Comment: This does work, but I cannot seem to be able to actually replace `word` with the given word. For example: `for word in commonWords :` `regex = "(?:^|\s)%s(?:\s|$)" % word` `re.sub(regex, "", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)` does not seem to work.

Comment: @user991710 create a new list and append re.sub to it.After the loop is over you will have your result

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this: without regex:

```
[ x for x in "hello how are you".split() if x not in stop_words ]
```

stop_words will be list of your stop words

Take a look at nltk:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stop = stopwords.words('english')
>>> text = "hello how are you, I am fine"
>>> words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
>>> words 
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', ',', 'I', 'am', 'fine']
>>> [x for x in words if x not in stop]
['hello', ',', 'I', 'fine']
>>> " ".join([x for x in words if x not in stop])
'hello , I fine'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I would then have to join the string again. I'm trying to avoid doing that, as the strings are extremely large (entire content of a website).

Comment: @user991710 using join you can join it

Comment: I realize that, I'm saying that I want to avoid having to do a join dozens of times on a string that is at least a couple thousand characters long.